# How can I define a templated function which takes a map and a lambda to search map-pair by value?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

What I currently have is this:

```
std::find_if(mmap.begin(), mmap.end(),
                                    [streamShm](const std::pair<int, StreamMapContainer> pair) {
                                        return pair.second.pcktRefShm->id() == streamShm->id();
                                    });
```

and I want to refactor this into a templated function, something like this (.cpp file):

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T, typename Lambda>
typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda) {
    return std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), lambda);
}
```

by this I am then able to call

```
findMapPairByValue(mmap, [streamShm](const std::pair<int, StreamMapContainer> pair) {
    return pair.second.pcktRefShm->id() == streamShm->id();
});
```

I declared the function as extern in my header file:

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T, typename Lambda>
extern typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda);
```

But the function above doesn't compile:

```
warning: 'findMapPairByValue' initialized and declared 'extern'
   31 | extern typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda);
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/.hpp:31:71: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'const'
   31 | extern typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda);
      |                                                                       ^~~~~
/.hpp:31:71: error: expected '(' before 'const'
   31 | extern typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda);
      |                                                                       ^~~~~
      |                                                                       (
/.hpp:31:85: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   31 | extern typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda);
      |                                                                                     ^
/.hpp:31:88: error: 'map' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::map'?
   31 | extern typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(typename const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda);
      |                                                                                        ^~~
      |                                                                                        std::map
```

Comment: Why do you make your template function `extern`?

Comment: @NutCracker I observed several times before that if I define a function inside a header-file and this header-file gets included at several places, the linker breaks due to multiple definitions of this function

Comment: You need to provide the definition of template function inside the header file

Comment: @binaryBigInt A template can occur multiple times and even multiple equal instantiations can be occur. The linker must not complain about. What broken compiler you are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the body of the function is right. You just incorrectly used `typename` inside parameter list:

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T, typename Lambda>
typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator findMapPairByValue(const Map<K, T> &map, const Lambda &lambda) {
    return std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), lambda);
}
```

Additionally it is worth noting that template function definition should be placed in header file, not inside *.cpp file